# How do I create a cell in flutter that has an element that extends to the bottom of the dynamically sized cell?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a cell that as this basic format:

```
|-----------------------------|
| column  |                   |
|  e1     | Expand (RichText) |
|  e2     |                   |
|  expand |                   |
|-----------------------------|
```

I have the following code to do this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(width: 2.0)),
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            width: 80.0,
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(color: Colors.red, height: 10.0),
                new Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 50.0,),
                // new Expanded(
                //   child: new Container(color: Colors.amber),
                // )
              ],
            ), 
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: new Text(widget.message)
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But I'm getting the following error out of Flutter:
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Is there a way to have that last expanded in the left most column take up as much room as it needs given the size of the RichText on the right and side?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example? In particular all those `Expanded` might be legal in the environment you place them but without knowing it properly it is hard to guess.

Comment: I've simplified the code and posted an example here:
https://github.com/fuzzybinary/flutter_layout_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want your list element to have the smallest height possible while having an element that take all the remaining space of a `Column`.

Such behaviour can be achieved thanks to [`IntrinsicHeight`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) widget

That widget makes sure it's child will take the smallest possible height instead of filling the screen.

=> Wrap your `Row` inside an [`IntrinsicHeight`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) widget and it will now work.

The end result would be :

```
new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(width: 2.0)),
  child: new IntrinsicHeight(
    child: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          width: 80.0,
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(color: Colors.red, height: 10.0),
              new Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 50.0,
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(color: Colors.amber),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        new Expanded(
          child: new Padding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: new Text("hello\n\n\n\n\n\nworld"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be few issues, but without a minimal working example I cannot be sure.

The point can be in the Columns: the right one it is not necessary, you can get the `RichText` overflow to new line and expand as needed by itself (consider `SingleChildScrollView` in case you want to keep the row fixed height); the left one needs to be bound somehow. You have few choices:

- you can wrap it in a `Container` with fixed height,
- you can have it in an object enabling the child to be cropped,
- you can require the `Column` to be tight containing its children with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

Cheers

Comment: Hi - I've updated the code in my question to the simplest example I could make + provided an example repo. Can you take another look?